# Creating a New Predictor Variable From a "Lagged Response Variable"?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cart, lags

Our TA in our stats class told us that when working with regression models, it is generally unadvisable to create a new predictor variable from a "lagged regression variable" (unless you are ready to consider very complicated regression models like "dynamic regression models").

As an example, suppose there are some students - you have repeated measurements on these students (e.g. age, weight, height) and the results (e.g. pass/fail) from fitness test taken by these student. As an example - suppose here are the test results for the same student over a period of years:

```
  student_id age weight height fitness
1          1  20    186   1.76    PASS
2          1  21    187   1.76    FAIL
3          1  22    191   1.77    FAIL
4          1  23    188   1.78    PASS
```

Suppose I wanted to add some new variables to this dataset (pass = 1, fail = 0):

```
  student_id age weight height fitness total_tests_taken result_previous_test cumulative_average
1          1  20    186   1.76       1                 0                   NA                 NA
2          1  21    187   1.76       0                 1                    1               1.00
3          1  22    191   1.77       0                 2                    0               0.50
4          1  23    188   1.78       1                 3                    0               0.33
```

Let's say that the goal is to build a model that models the relationship between passing the fitness test and historical results from students. Supposedly, these new variables that I have created are not to be inserted into a regression model due to assumption violations.

However, I have the following question - suppose instead of a regression model, I decide to use a model like a "Decision Tree" (e.g. CART, C4.5, CHAID) which in theory has fewer assumption restrictions compared to a regression model. **Using models such as Decision Trees, is it now "more permissible" to create new predictor variables based on "lagged values of the covariates" as compared to regression models?**

Answer (score 3):

First, use of lagged regressors in linear regression is a fairly standard practice. You will find it in most econometrics textbooks, even on an introductory level. Time series models are a bit more complicated than cross sectional ones due to an additional dimension of dependence (time dependence). This shows up when deriving properties of estimators such as consistency and asymptotic normality of OLS. The TA probably does not want you to deal with this at an early stage in the course but they should not be against that in general.

Second, while trees and linear regression are different models, I do not think one can accommodate time dependence and lagged regressors more or less easily than the other. The model formulations are equally straightforward. The facts that (1) we study properties of OLS but not tree estimators in introductory statistics or econometrics courses and that (2) proofs for OLS get a bit harder when considering the time dimension do not imply that the properties of tree estimators are unaffected.

Comment: This is not an answer from a reputable source, but I think it will not hurt to share it nevertheless.

Comment: @ Richard Hardy: Thank you for your answer! I thought that if you use a regression model like Logistic Regression, creating predictors from lagged responses will violate assumptions?

Comment: In this example, is it unreasonable to create a logistic regression model that estimates the probability of passing the next exam based on the results of previous exams?

Comment: @stats_noob, I do not think logistic regression and trees used as predictive models have inherent differences regarding incorporation of lagged regressors. There may be some nuance about properties of the estimators, but again I do not think trees are inherently better in this regard. But this is just my general intuition, not an answer from a reputable source.

Answer (score 2):

While in a regression setting using a lagged value or its transformation would lead you to something similar to an Autoregressive Model with covariates (which then trains and behaves differently from a normal linear regression), it would be perfectly acceptable when using decision trees and derivate algorithms.

However, if you plan on using a training-testing split (or CV) on your data to optimize the choice of some hyperparameters, it is important that you do so respecting the "direction" of the time component - i.e. do not train on "future" data to test on "past" data.

Comment: @ Davide ND: Thank you so much for your reply! Can you recommend any sources that confirm that "lagged variables would be perfectly acceptable when using decision trees"? Thank you!